# How can I hide tabs when they are empty?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to create a function where I will be able to hide a tab if it's empty, based on tab's `content-id`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.bdt-switcher-item-content').children().each(function() {
    if ($(this div).is(':empty'))
      $('div[content-id="' + $(this).attr('content-id') + '"]').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bdt-switcher-wrapper">
  <div id="bdt-tab-content-a49ef84" class="bdt-switcher bdt-switcher-item-content">
    <div content-id="tab-1" class="">
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div content-id="tab-2" class="bdt-active">
      <div>I am tab #2 content</div>
    </div>
    <div content-id="tab-3" class="">
      <div> I am tab #3 content.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you wrong here:

```
$(this div)
```

See my example, you must declare what you want so in this case "div" before use this.
Work example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.bdt-switcher-item-content').children().each(function() {
    if ($("div",this).is(':empty'))
      $('div[content-id="' + $(this).attr('content-id') + '"]').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bdt-switcher-wrapper">
  <div id="bdt-tab-content-a49ef84" class="bdt-switcher bdt-switcher-item-content">
    <div content-id="tab-1" class="">
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div content-id="tab-2" class="bdt-active">
      <div>I am tab #2 content</div>
    </div>
    <div content-id="tab-3" class="">
      <div> I am tab #3 content.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks , I used this code but it still not working:

http://casa.palette-webdesign.ir/products/electron-series-67-4/

Comment: How can you see on your console : `"$ is not a function"`, change the position of the script at the bottom of the page